# How to work with reverse formula in c#. convert Controller datetime format to normal date time using formula?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I am working with Controller device, which maintain user attendance logs. Controller store logs time details like below:

| Controller Time | Actual Time |
| --- | --- |
| 690581614 | 2021-06-26 20:13:34.000 |
| 690581620 | 2021-06-26 20:13:40.000 |
| 690590751 | 2021-06-26 22:45:51.000 |

It uses internal formula to convert normal date to number date like below

```
((Year - 2000) * 12 * 31 + (Month - 1) * 31 + (Day - 1)) * (24 * 60 * 60) + Hour * 60 * 60 + Minute * 60 + Second;
```

If we consider our date time is  **"2021-06-26 22:45:51.000"** then it look like

```
((2021 - 2000) * 12 * 31 + (06 - 1) * 31 + (26 - 1)) * (24 * 60 * 60) + 22 * 60 * 60 + 45 * 60 + 51;
```

once we get result : 690590751

Means **690590751** (Controoler DT) == **"2021-06-26 22:45:51.000"**.

---I am getting below values which i want to convert to actual date..Please help me to get proper conversion formula for converting from **Controller DT to Normal Date for C#.**

690590751 => Normal Date Formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate a `DateTime` from the number like this:

```cs
public static DateTime ControllerValueToDateTime(int value)
{
    int seconds = value % 60;
    value /= 60;
    int minutes = value % 60;
    value /= 60;
    int hours = value % 24;
    value /= 24;
    int day = (value % 31) + 1;
    value /= 31;
    int month = (value % 12) + 1;
    value /= 12;
    int year = 2000 + value;
    return new DateTime(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
}
```

`%` is the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-), so `63 % 60` would return `3`, as would `123 % 60`, etc. So we can slowly remove individual parts from the number to get the component values, and then build a `DateTime` instance using them.

Testing this, we get the following results:

| Controller Time | Actual Time |
| --- | --- |
| 690581614 | 2021-06-26 20:13:34.000 |
| 690581620 | 2021-06-26 20:13:40.000 |
| 690590751 | 2021-06-26 22:45:51.000 |

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/IXXA83405)